# Compare multiple dictionaries for entry based on two values within dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have two python dictionaries, and I need an efficient way to iterate over one dictionary checking multiple values per-entry against another dictionary. If the entry does not exist I need to add that entry from one dictionary to the source dictionary.

I have tried different methods such as itter() over the two dictionary values and using "in" to see if the value exists but the logic is broken somewhere.

```py
for key, value in export_data.iteritems():
  if  value['computer_id'] and value['computer_name'] in import_data.iteritems():
```

If `computer_id` and `computer_name` are in `import_data` then continue and if not then add the missing dictionary item from import_data to the export_data dictionary.

In the example data below '`import_data`' has a extra item "`host-c`" and I would like that added to the export_data dictionary.

The part I am having a hard time with is there is also a record for "host-g" but the computer_id is the same as host-a in export_data so I don't want to add that entry.

Only unique items where both computer_name and computer_id are different.

Example Data:

```
export_data = 
{u'host-a': {'computer_id': [u'6353a65387'], 'computer_name': ['host-a'], 'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']}, {u'host-b': {'computer_id': [u'635365d387'], 'computer_name': ['host-b'], 'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']}

import_data = 
{u'host-a': {'computer_id': [u'6353a65387'], 'computer_name': ['host-a'], 'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']}, {u'host-b': {'computer_id': [u'635365d387'], 'computer_name': ['host-b'], 'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']},{u'host-c': {'computer_id': [u'6353654d387'], 'computer_name': ['host-c'], 'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']},{u'host-g': {'computer_id': [u'6353a65387'], 'computer_name': ['host-g'], 'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']}
```

Comment: What would you like to see happen if the key exists in both but the value is different?

Comment: You should give an example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way around iterating through both dicts and comparing the values manually. Experimenting with your code I got this:

```
export_data = {
    u'host-a': {
        'computer_id': [u'6353a65387'],
        'computer_name': ['host-a'],
        'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']
        },
    u'host-b': {
        'computer_id': [u'635365d387'],
        'computer_name': ['host-b'],
        'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']
        }
    }

import_data = {
    u'host-a': {
        'computer_id': [u'6353a65387'],
        'computer_name': ['host-a'],
        'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']
        },
    u'host-b': {
        'computer_id': [u'635365d387'],
        'computer_name': ['host-b'],
        'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']
        },
    u'host-c': {
        'computer_id': [u'6353654d387'],
        'computer_name': ['host-c'],
        'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']
        },
    u'host-g': {
        'computer_id': [u'6353a65387'],
        'computer_name': ['host-g'],
        'first_observed': ['Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019']
        }
    }

print(export_data)

additional_export_data = []

for im_key, im_value in import_data.items():
    found_in_export = False

    for ex_key, ex_value in export_data.items():
        if ex_value['computer_id'][0] == im_value['computer_id'][0] and ex_value['computer_name'][0] == im_value['computer_name'][0]:
            found_in_export = True

    if not found_in_export:
        additional_export_data.append((im_key, im_value))

        print(im_key, im_value['computer_id'][0])
        print("")

for key, value in additional_export_data:
    export_data[key] = value

print(export_data)
```

This adds key-value-pairs from `import_data` to `export_data` if there is no entry in `export_data` with the same `computer_id` **and** `computer_name`.

---

Also I don't know why your `export_data` and `import_data` structured the way they are.
The keys of the dictionaries are the same as the `computer_name` values.
The `computer_id`, `computer_name` and `first_observed` are each a list even though it doesn't make sense to me.

Maybe you have a reason why you structured your data this way but if not I would recommend doing the following:

- get rid of `computer_name` in the sub dictionaries
- store the values of `computer_id` and `first_observed` just as string, not as a string in a list

If you do this, the code looks like this:

```
export_data = {
    u'host-a': {
        'computer_id': u'6353a65387',
        'first_observed': 'Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019'
        },
    u'host-b': {
        'computer_id': u'635365d387',
        'first_observed': 'Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019'
        }
    }

import_data = {
    u'host-a': {
        'computer_id': u'6353a65387',
        'first_observed': 'Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019'
        },
    u'host-b': {
        'computer_id': u'635365d387',
        'first_observed': 'Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019'
        },
    u'host-c': {
        'computer_id': u'6353654d387',
        'first_observed': 'Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019'
        },
    u'host-g': {
        'computer_id': u'6353a65387',
        'first_observed': 'Wed Jul 24 13:57:56  2019'
        }
    }

print(export_data)

additional_export_data = []

for im_key, im_value in import_data.items():
    found_in_export = False

    for ex_key, ex_value in export_data.items():
        if ex_value['computer_id'] == im_value['computer_id'] and ex_key == im_key:
            found_in_export = True

    if not found_in_export:
        additional_export_data.append((im_key, im_value))

        print(im_key, im_value['computer_id'])
        print("")

for key, value in additional_export_data:
    export_data[key] = value

print(export_data)
```

Comment: Thanks Marv. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation ;) To show to others that your question is answered and my answer is correct you can check the tick next to it (under the up- and downvotes). That will also give you and me some reputation :)